# Oracle Reports (6i): Get difference of two items from two different queries (Multi Query Report)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oraclereports

I have an Oracle 6i report with two complex queries (Q1 and Q2) connected by data link. The report was developed by some other developer who is not available now. Multiple columns are being displayed in report.

Q1 has a column `Total_Issuance` and Q2 has a column `Total_Consumption`. I have to display their difference on report. I am using a formula column to get the difference and then binding a display field to this formula column to show on report.

But since the formula column is outside both the queries, I am getting following errors.

> REP-1517: column 'CF_1' references column 'Total_Issuance', which has incompatible frequency.
>
> REP-1517: column 'CF_1' references column 'Total_Consumption', which has incompatible frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the formula column is outside both queries, create two additional **summary** columns (outside of both queries):

- `cs_tot_iss`, which will sum `total_issuance`
- `cs_tot_con`, which will sum `total_consumption`

Now modify formula column so that its source are newly created summary columns, e.g. let it

```
return :cs_tot_iss + :cs_tot_con;
```

As of paper layout: you don't have to display `cs_tot_iss` nor `cs_tot_con` (as you already have those values via `total_issuance` and `total_consumption`), just add formula column.

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot! your suggestion has worked but only for the first record. It repeats the same value for all the next records. How to correct it further please?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new calculated field to the query that is the detail query (I asume it's Q2).
In this calculated field you can simply use:

```
return :Total_Issuance - :Total_Consumption;
```

to calculate the difference.